# Force mysqldump encoding

Tags: linux, mysql, character-encoding

I have two mysql servers, viewed from the same mysql client, right_server is rendering the french characters correctly, wrong_server is not. Encoding is the same :

```
$ mysql -h right_server -NBe "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%'"
$ mysql -h wrong_server -NBe "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%'"
```

give same results :

```
character_set_client     utf8
character_set_connection utf8
character_set_database   utf8
character_set_filesystem binary
character_set_results    utf8
character_set_server     utf8
character_set_system     utf8
```

I use mysqldump to check tables structures are the same :

```
$ mysqldump -h right_server db MY_TABLE | grep MY_COL
$ mysqldump -h wrong_server db MY_TABLE | grep MY_COL
```

but one of the comment is not rendered correctly :

```
  `MY_COL` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'associé à',
  `MY_COL` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'associ. .',
```

(result with `mysqldump --default-character-set=UTF8 --no-data` is the same)

In `wrong_server` characters seem correctly stored :

```
[wrong_server]$ mysql -e 'show create table db.MY_TABLE\G'
  `MY_COL` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8_bin COMMENT 'associé à',
```

**How to force mysqldump encoding ?**

Note: the only difference I see between servers is

```
character_sets_dir      /.../mysql.../share/charsets/
```

in `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%'` of one server and no utf file defined in this directory.